# Change the type of webform component in Drupal

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-webform

Can we change the type of webform component using hook_form_alter.
I mean, I have a select box and I want to convert it to a simple textfield using form_alter.
Is it possible in drupal 7.
Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

you can use hook_node_load() to edit component of the loaded web form.